# JavaScript basic Arithmetic

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a simple JavaScript Arithmetic.
   The user enters values, and the arithmetic is done and then plugged into "h4"

```
<h4 id="sum1"><h4>
<h4 id="sum2"></h4>
<h4 id="sum3"></h4>
<h4 id="sum4"></h4>


<form name="arithmetic" method="post">
    <fieldset><legend>Enter a Number Here!</legend>
    <label>First Number Here</label>
    <input type="text" name="inPutN1" />
    <br/>
    <label>Second Number Here</label>
    <input type="text" name="inPutN2" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="enter" onClick="solve(inPutN1,inPutN2)" />
    <input type="reset" value="clear"/>
    </fieldset>
<script> 
    function solve(sum1,sum2,sum3,sum4) {
        var operand1 = parseInt(arithmetic.inPutN1.value); 
        var operand2 = parseInt(arithmetic.inPutN2.value); 
        var sum1= operand1 + operand2; 
            document.getElementById("sum1").innerHTML=sum1;
        var sum2= operand1 - operand2;
            document.getElementById("sum2").innerHTML=sum2;
        var sum3= operand1 * operand2;
            document.getElementById("sum3").innerHTML=sum3;
        var sum4= operand1 / operand2;
            document.getElementById("sum4").innerHTML=sum4;
        }





   </script>
```

Any Help would be appreciated as to why this is not working

Comment: What exactly is *not working*?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What precisely is not working?

Comment: The Value appears and disappears really quick, like it is running in a loop or something and writing over itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your enter button input type from "submit" to "button".

```
<input type="button" value="enter" onClick="solve(inPutN1,inPutN2)" />
```

You don't need to submit a form just to run javascript code.

Comment: Ding, ding, some other things wrong with it, but you were the one. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the form tag that you open.  Right now that isn't ever closed, that could be throwing off the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this it's work using the names of the components

```
var operand1 = parseInt(document.arithmetic.inPutN1.value); 
var operand2 = parseInt(document.arithmetic.inPutN2.value);
```

Comment: I did an alert test, var operand1 and operand 2 seemed fine on their own.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem because you are using a submit button, and whe the function is called, the submit evet reload the page ... this works

```
<h4 id="sum1"><h4>
<h4 id="sum2"></h4>
<h4 id="sum3"></h4>
<h4 id="sum4"></h4>


<form name="arithmetic" method="post">
    <fieldset><legend>Enter a Number Here!</legend>
    <label>First Number Here</label>
    <input type="text" name="inPutN1" />
    <br/>
    <label>Second Number Here</label>
    <input type="text" name="inPutN2" />
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="enter" onClick="solve(inPutN1,inPutN2)" />
    <input type="reset" value="clear"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<script> 
    function solve() {
        var operand1 = parseInt(arithmetic.inPutN1.value); 
        var operand2 = parseInt(arithmetic.inPutN2.value); 
        var sum1= operand1 + operand2; 
            document.getElementById("sum1").innerHTML=sum1;
        var sum2= operand1 - operand2;
            document.getElementById("sum2").innerHTML=sum2;
        var sum3= operand1 * operand2;
            document.getElementById("sum3").innerHTML=sum3;
        var sum4= operand1 / operand2;
            document.getElementById("sum4").innerHTML=sum4;
        }
   </script>
```